# awk basename as a column variable

Tags: awk, filenames

I would like the entire original file with the last column being the file name (without the path name).  It seems simple, but every attempt has failed to deliver. My aim to do this as a loop where FLD0037 becomes FLD0${ID}.

I have tried the following:

```
cat FLD0037.txt | awk '{print $0, FILENAME;}' >FLD0037.test1.txt
```

test.1 gives - in the final column.

```
cat FLD0037.txt | awk '{print $0, basename(FILENAME);}' >FLD0037.test2.txt
```

test.2 is an empty file

```
cat FLD0037.txt | awk '{print $0, basename;}' >FLD0037.test3.txt
cat FLD0037.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $0, $NF;}' >FLD0037.test4.txt
cat FLD0037.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $NF;}' >FLD0037.test5.txt
cat FLD0037.txt | awk '{print basename $0;}' >FLD0037.test6.txt
```

test.3, test.5 and test.6 look like the original file, nothing written in the final column.

test.4 is the original file with the data duplicated in new columns.

Thanks,

Comment: When you ran `cat FLD0037.txt | awk '{print $0, basename(FILENAME);}' >FLD0037.test2.txt` and noticed that `test.2 is an empty file` didn't you also notice the far more important and useful error message `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=file FNR=1) fatal: function 'basename' not defined` or similar? Do NOT do this in a shell loop as awk is perfectly capable of opening and closing multiple files and it'll do so much more efficiently, robustly, and portably than a shell loop. Do you have GNU awk and, if so, what version? If not - get gawk 4.0 or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cat` is more than [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) here because Awk ends up reading standard input (hence the `-` pseudo-filename) instead of the actual file.

As always, the fix is easy: don't use a useless `cat`.

```
awk '{print $0, FILENAME;}' FLD0037.txt >FLD0037.test1.txt
```

Comment: Works well, the only improvement I would ask is how to write it when the entire file path is specified and to only have the file name without the path as the column variable.

Comment: `{ l = split(FILENAME, b, "/"); print $0, b[l] }`?

Comment: Or as an optimization `FNR==1{ l=split(FILENAME, b, "/"); basename=b[l] } { print $0, basename }`

Comment: Never use `l` (the letter `el`) as a variable name as it looks FAR too much like `1` (the number `one`), indistinguishable in some fonts. I actually can't tell in your comment if you're indexing `b` by the variable named `l` or the number `1` but it LOOKs like you might be using the number `1` which would be wrong.